# Duda Stack View

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

He agrupado varios botones dentro de un Stack View. Una vez aplicadas las restricciones queda perfecto en un iPhone SE, pero al pasar a una pantalla superior como un iPhone 7 Plus o superior, todo el Stack View se achata a lo alto.

He intentado añadir una Size Class para modificar la medida del alto (de 44 a 50) solo en la vista del iPhone 7 Plus pero no funciona.

Como puedo modificar el alto del Stack View de manera personalizada para cada tamaño de pantalla (siempre en Portrait)?

Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo idea como tenés los constraints, supongo que los tenés en el stackView. Si es así podrías probar con poner los constraint de altura y ancho en los botones y cambiar los del stackView. De esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]